# Draw line in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I need your help. I am newbie in Phaser 3. I want to create game with simple rules. There are 36 dots, which situated in 6 rows. Player needs to unite dots with a line, but he can only unite dots with same color and union can happen only vertically and horizontally. So, you can't draw daigonal line. When you will finish union, dots will vanish. How I can realize union with line? My current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="js/phaser.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        let config = {
            type: Phaser.AUTO,
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            backgroundColor: '#f0ebeb',
            physics: {
                default: 'arcade',
                arcade: {
                    gravity: { y: 300 },
                    debug: false
                }
            },
            scene: {
                preload: preload,
                create: create,
                update: update
            },

            scale: {
                autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH
            }
        };

        let game = new Phaser.Game(config);
        let items = [];

        function preload() {
            for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++)
                this.load.image(i, 'img/' + i + '.png');
        }
        function create() {
            let x = 100;
            let y = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
                if (i % 6 === 0) {
                    y += 85;
                    x = 100;
                }
                this.add.image(x, y, getRandomInt(5).toString())
                x += 125;
            }
        }
        function update() { }

        function getRandomInt(max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I want something like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just *allow* the user **only** to select (draw a line) to next valid circles.

> *A valid circle being, on the s**ame row** or **same column** or **same color** or **max union length** or **...***

And when the drawing is finished I would, only allow **union**, when more than one circle is selected *(is in the given path)*.

**Here a short demo, how it could look like:**

```js
let config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    scene: { create }
};

let game = new Phaser.Game(config);

let isDragging =  false;
let lineStartPosition =  {x:0 , y:0};
let currentPath = [];
let currentColor;

let line;
let pathGraphics;

function create (){
    let cicles = []
    for(let rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < 4; rowIdx++ ){
        for(let colIdx = 0; colIdx < 2; colIdx++ ){
            let circle = this.add.circle(50 + 100 * rowIdx, 50 + 100 * colIdx, 25,  0x6666ff).setOrigin(.5);
            // Just to test a different color
            if(rowIdx + colIdx ==2){
              circle.fillColor = 0xff0000;
            }
            circle.setInteractive();
            cicles.push(circle);
        }        
    }

    line = this.add.line(0,0, 0,0, 100, 100,  0xffffff).setOrigin(0);
    line.setLineWidth(5);
    line.visible = false;
    
    pathGraphics = this.add.graphics();
    
    // adding the events to the scene
    this.input.on('pointerdown', dragStart);
    this.input.on('pointerup', dragEnd);
    this.input.on('pointermove', drag); 
}

function dragStart(pointer, gameObjects){
    if(gameObjects.length == 0){
      return;
    }
    isDragging = true;
    
    // remember Starting Color
    currentColor = gameObjects[0].fillColor;
    
    // initialize Path
    currentPath = [gameObjects[0]];

    // draw/save last segment of the path
    lineStartPosition.x = gameObjects[0].x;
    lineStartPosition.y = gameObjects[0].y;
    
    line.x = gameObjects[0].x;
    line.y = gameObjects[0].y;
    line.setTo(0, 0, 0, 0);
    line.visible = true;
}

function drag(pointer, gameObjects ){
    if(isDragging == true){
        // Check If Circle is allowed to be added, to path
        // Here you would also check if the line is horizontal or vertical  (this part is currently not implemented)
        if(gameObjects[0] && currentPath.indexOf(gameObjects[0]) === -1 && currentColor == gameObjects[0].fillColor){
          currentPath.push(gameObjects[0]);
          
          line.x = gameObjects[0].x;
          line.y = gameObjects[0].y;
          
          lineStartPosition.x = gameObjects[0].x;
          lineStartPosition.y = gameObjects[0].y;

        }
        line.setTo(0, 0, pointer.x - lineStartPosition.x, pointer.y - lineStartPosition.y);
        drawPath();
    }
}

function drawPath(){
    pathGraphics.clear();
    if(currentPath.length > 0){
      pathGraphics.lineStyle(10, 0xffffff);
      let path = new Phaser.Curves.Path(currentPath[0].x, currentPath[0].y);
      for(let idx = 1; idx < currentPath.length; idx++){
        let point = currentPath[idx];
        path.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
      }
      path.draw(pathGraphics);
    }
}

function dragEnd(pointer, gameObjects){
    if(gameObjects.length == 0){
      return;
    }
    
    if(currentPath.length < 2) {
      console.info('No valid path');
      return;
    } else { 
      console.info(`Valid Union path, length: ${currentPath.length}`);
    }

    line.visible = false;
    isDragging = false;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```